# How do I remove duplicates in paging

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

table1 & table2:

[table1 & table2 http://aftabfarda.parsfile.com/1.png](http://aftabfarda.parsfile.com/1.png)

```
SELECT     *
FROM         (SELECT DISTINCT dbo.tb1.ID, dbo.tb1.name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tb1.id DESC) AS row
FROM         dbo.tb1 INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tb2 ON dbo.tb1.ID = dbo.tb2.id_tb1) AS a
WHERE     row BETWEEN 1 AND 7
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Result:

[Result... http://aftabfarda.parsfile.com/3.png](http://aftabfarda.parsfile.com/3.png)

(id 11 Repeated 3 times)

How can I have this output:

```
ID  name    row
--  ------  ---
11  user11  1
10  user10  2
9   user9   3
8   user8   4
7   user7   5
6   user6   6
5   user5   7
```

Comment: Is that all of tb2 in your screensshot?

Comment: yes ,screenshot tb1 and tb2 in [link](http://aftabfarda.parsfile.com/1.png)

Comment: In which case user11 should never return, as there's no corresponding record in `tb2`

Comment: a suggestion , if you are using just these data , you can create a column in first table [idGroup] and have in second table just id and group (in this case just 2 entry) , and save space and problems :) +1 for info/pics

Comment: table2 is [link](http://aftabfarda.parsfile.com/2.png)

Comment: No, this is just a small example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively to [@Andomar's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187066/how-do-i-remove-duplicates-in-paging/10187173#10187173), you could use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER` and rank the rows first (in the subquery), *then* apply `DISTINCT` (in the outer query):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ID,
  name,
  row
FROM (
  SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.name,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t1.ID DESC) AS row
  FROM dbo.tb1 t1
    INNER JOIN dbo.tb2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.id_tb1
) AS a
WHERE row BETWEEN 1 AND 7
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Similar, but not quite the same, although both might boil down to the same query plan, I'm just not sure. Worth testing, I think.

And, of course, you could also try a *semi*-join instead of a proper join, in the form of either `IN` or `EXISTS`, to prevent duplicates in the first place:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  name,
  row
FROM (
  SELECT
    ID,
    name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) AS row
  FROM dbo.tb1
  WHERE ID IN (SELECT id_tb1 FROM dbo.tb2)
  /* Or:
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.tb2
    WHERE id_tb1 = dbo.tb1.ID
  )
  */
) AS a
WHERE row BETWEEN 1 AND 7
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

You could apply `distinct` before `row_number` using a subquery:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (order by tbl.id desc) as row
        ,       *
        from    (
                select  distinct t1.ID
                ,       tb1.name
                from    dbo.tb1 as t1
                join    dbo.tb2 as t2
                on      t1.ID = t2.id_tb1
                ) as sub_dist
        ) as sub_with_rn
where   row between 1 and 7
```

Comment: The multi-part identifier "tb1.id" could not be bound.

Comment: Added aliases to the table, does that help?

Comment: select * from (
 select  *,row_number() over (order by id desc) as row
from (


     select  distinct tb1.ID
                ,       tb1.name
                from    dbo.tb1 
                join    dbo.tb2 
                on      dbo.tb1.ID = dbo.tb2.id_tb1


)as sub_t1) as sub_t2
 where row between 1 and 7