# Keeping nested rows together with dynamic ORDER BY and LIMIT / pagination

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql, parent

Consider the case where you need to display data like this:

```
Parent 1 info
    Child 1A info
    Child 1B info
    ...
Parent 2 info
    Child 2A info
    Child 2B info
    ...
```

Note that the children only go one level deep, so there's no need to get into "nested sets" at the database level. For example, in my current project, data needs to be displayed like this:

```
First name  | Last name | City  | ...
---------------------------------
John        | Doe       | Denver

    Sales:
    ---------------------
    Date    | Total | ...
    -----------------
    Jan 1   | $100
    Jan 15  | $200
    Feb 1   | $100

Suzie       | Springer  | New York

    Sales:
    ---------------------
    Date    | Total | ...
    -----------------
    ...
```

My question is about the SQL needed to get the data for this page while still doing pagination through use of the LIMIT clause (or equivalent).

In this case the accounts with the most recent sales should be listed first, but of course each account needs to have ALL its sales under it, up to one year ago.

Let me ask about a simpler case first: let's say the sort order didn't matter. Then I could simply order by the account ID (simplified example):

```
SELECT sh.account_id, a.first_name, a.last_name,
    sh.sale_id, sh.total, sh.payment_time
FROM sales_header sh
JOIN account a on sh.account_id = a.account_id
WHERE a.account_type = 'parent'
ORDER BY sh.account_id
```

But when pagination is introduced, how would one make sure that all the sales for a particular account were kept together? It would be difficult to know how big the LIMIT should be.

Now let's add the real sort order that's needed:

```
SELECT sh.account_id, a.first_name, a.last_name,
    sh.sale_id, sh.total, sh.payment_time
FROM sales_header sh
JOIN account a on sh.account_id = a.account_id
WHERE a.account_type = 'parent'
ORDER BY sh.payment_time
```

When retrieving ALL rows, there's no problem -- I can simply run the query, then index the results by account_id in my application code (PHP in this case).

But if I add a LIMIT, then I may not be getting all the sales for each account, especially for an account that has both old sales and recent sales.

I have come up with a solution to this, but it's rather complicated, especially since I'm dealing with dynamic query parameters rather than the simplified version I'm showing here. My solution was to run two separate queries.

First, get all the account IDs that I need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sh.account_id
FROM sales_header sh
JOIN account a on sh.account_id = a.account_id
WHERE a.account_type = 'parent'
ORDER BY sh.payment_time
LIMIT 10
```

Then, put the IDs into a PHP array called $account_ids, then build the query that returns the actual results needed to display the page:

```
$sql = 'SELECT sh.account_id, a.first_name, a.last_name,
    sh.sale_id, sh.total, sh.payment_time
FROM sales_header sh
JOIN account a on sh.account_id = a.account_id
WHERE sh.account_id IN ('. implode(',', $account_ids). ')
ORDER BY sh.payment_time';
```

This of course could also be accomplished in a single query by putting the SQL of the
first query where the implode() function is, something like:

```
WHERE sh.account_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT sh.account_id ... LIMIT 10)
```

But that raises concerns about the limit in the subquery and database portability -
I'm using a framework that lets you set the limit using a limit() method which is portable
to different databases, but I'm not sure how it would react if I tried to use a limit in a subquery
like this with SQL Server, for example.

So, my real question is: is this the best way of solving the problem, or is there an alternate (simpler) solution? What have you done in similar situations?

Comment: Also of interest, especially if you're using SQL Server:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187066/how-do-i-remove-duplicates-in-paging

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    sh.account_id, a.first_name, a.last_name,
    sh.sale_id, sh.total, sh.payment_time
FROM
    sales_header sh
    inner JOIN
    account a on sh.account_id = a.account_id
    inner join (
        SELECT sh.account_id, max(sh.payment_time) payment_time
        FROM
            sales_header sh
            inner JOIN
            account a on sh.account_id = a.account_id
        WHERE a.account_type = 'parent'
        group by sh.account_id
        order by 2 desc
        limit 10
    ) acs on acs.account_id = a.account_id
ORDER BY acs.payment_time desc, acs.account_id, sh.payment_time desc
```

I tried to make it db agnostic but the `limit` clause must be translated to `select top 10` in Sql Server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is the `order by 2` is a typo? If not, what purpose does it serve? Is `acs` supposed to be the alias for the subuery (looks like the subquery is also missing the `on` statement)?

Comment: Ok, I figured out what `order by 2` means...to order by the second field in the SELECT statement, in this case `max(sh.payment_time)`. Cool, I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: Cool, I tested it out and when I added `acs` after the subquery it worked. I'm wondering, is there any advantage to this over the `WHERE sh.account_id IN` approach I mentioned (the single query version)? Or is it just an alternative?

Comment: @Matt I added the `acs`. I think the `limit` does not work in subqueries in MySQL.

Comment: The `limit` works just fine in subqueries in MySQL, in both your version and mine, thanks.